# preg_match_all para localizar texto entre strings

Tags: php

Gostaria de pegar o texto entre `"play_url":"` e `","` usando o preg_match_all do PHP, só que essas aspas estão me complicando e nem sei o rumo que seria para o código de rastreio, oque tenho atualmente é isso:

```
$texto: '"play_url":"http:/video.server.com/","'
preg_match_all('/"play_url"(.*?) ","/i', $texto, $link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está quase certo, exceto pelo espaço após o grupo e falta também o `:"` após o `"play_url"`:

```
                          :"
                           ↓   ↓
preg_match_all('/"play_url"(.*) ","/i', $texto, $link);
```

O lazy (`?`) também não precisa neste caso, já que aparentemente não há a possibilidade de ter outro `","` na string.

Ficaria:

```
<?
$texto = '"play_url":"http:/video.server.com/","';
preg_match_all('/"play_url":"(.*)","/i', $texto, $link);
var_dump($link[1]); // mostra array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "http:/video.server.com/" }
?>
```

Para printar o valor:

```
echo $link[1][0]; // http:/video.server.com/
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/66eCCS)**

Comment: `.*?` aceita também "nada" (string vazia), ou seja, se a string for `"play_url":"",`, a URL ficará vazia. Dá para melhorar colocando por exemplo `[^"]+` (uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa que não seja aspas), ou ainda algo como `[^"]{10,}` (pelo menos 10 caracteres que não sejam aspas) o que já garante que pelo menos tem que ter alguma coisa entre as aspas. Se quiser ir até o limite (ou além), dá para fazer expressões cada vez maiores e mais complexas, que verificam se é uma URL válida: https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738

Comment: É verdade. Mas eu considerei que a string não virá vazia neste caso, ou seja, sempre terá algo. Como a pergunta não indica nada no sentido da possibilidade de estar vazia, eu restringi a resposta ao escopo da pergunta. Mas tb é válido quem quiser postar uma resposta mais completa, eu que muito pouca vezes faço isso, exceto em casos onde é explícita a possibilidade da string vir vazia. Ou eu poderia trocar o `.*?` por `.+?`. Por ser bem simples a questão, acho que nem precisaria do `?`.